# VB.Net 2010 Resources Not Working After Importing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, resources

When I go to set the Image on a regular `Button`, and get to the Select Resource dialog, I can select an imported resource, but the preview does not show up. This is true for all of the imported resource images, not just one of them. If I try to go on and hit OK, it still says "(None)" in the Image property of the `Button`.

I've tried deleting the resource files and re-importing, both from the Select Resource dialog, and from Project Settings -> Resources. Under Project Settings -> Resources, the images show up just fine. All of the images are PNG's and were previously working yesterday.

Any suggestions?

[image: Select Resource Dialog]

Comment: Please provide a description of the file and the `Button`.

Comment: Is the file format of document_open one of the supported file types for Image? bmp, gif, jpeg, png, tiff

Comment: @APrough, yes. it's a PNG.

Comment: @Joiner, it's a normal button of class `Button`.

Comment: Did you changed any properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by doing the following:

- Remove all image resources from the program.
- Look through all of `*.Designer.vb` files of for lingering references to the any of the image resources (I found a few).
- Close completely out of Visual Studio.
- Re-open the project.
- Add the image resources back.